# How can i make gauge highchart chart responsive

Tags: javascript, highcharts, developer-tools, angular-fullstack, angular-highcharts

Please refer below jsfiddle currently litle and legend is not responsive how can i make it responsive [text] without title it works fine but i also want title and legend resonsive in chart
Please help me out to make gauge high chart responsive with title as well as legend .
I attached below link that i tried to make responsive : [[Demo Link]:

'https://jsfiddle.net/khushbu_mistry/sxu8nfyj/1/'

Please help me out to make it responsive

Answer (score 0):

Since your solution of updating `pane.size` using `load()`/`render()` generates such problems with the responsiveness of the title and legend, I suggest using the default solution, which is the `responsive` property that allows you to adjust the chart configuration to the appropriate resolution:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  ...
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 630
      },
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
            height: 300
        },
        pane: [{
          center: ['50%', '95%'],
          size: '180%',
        }],
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1tf93mo2/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive